# Auto complete ERROR 404 in HTML (using ASP.NET and JQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, http-status-code-404

For some reason in asp.net project, my autocomplete won't work, I have tried different methods from using Data source in data connection but to no avail. I have already created a database for it called Diagnose but for some reason, it displays error 404 on jquery.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#search-diagnosis").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = {
                    searchdetails: $('#search-diagnosis').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "SearchController.cs/GetSearch",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) { return { value: item } }))
                    },
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="search">
    <input id="search-diagnosis" class="w-75" type="text" placeholder="Start typing your diagnois...">
</div>
```

**Here is CS code:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetSearch(string searchdetails)
{
    List<string> search = new List<string>();
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mybase.database"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
    string sqlquery = string.Format("select Name from [dbo].[Diagnose] where Name LIKE '%{0}%'", searchdetails);
    sqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
    SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        search.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
    }
    sqlconn.Close();
    return search; 
}
```

It displays error:

[image: This error]
When I open the `jquery-1.8.0.js:8214` it shows me this `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );`

I'm stuck at this problem for a while so any help would be great, thanks in advance :D <3

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact question earlier today (or yesterday)? Because I believe some other user commented that this url `SearchController.cs/GetSearch` is wrong.

Comment: So what should I change to fix this problem, I tried just putting Search/GetSearch but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It is returning 404 not found. I think that GetSearch should be inside of an aspx or an ascx file. Webmethod works in System.Web context and in some point it will require Page.

Comment: So I should change controller?

Comment: Are you using a controller? is that right you don't need to add the extension file in your request. I mean, remove the .cs url: "API/SearchController/GetSearch". 
If thought that you were using a WebForm project because you add the attribute WebMethod. On an MVC project you don't need to add WebMethod attribute. You should add the attribute ApiController and set the Route if is needed.