# What is the easiest way to make autocomplete using CSHTML

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, controller

For like few days I have been trying to make autocomplete in ASP.NET for my project. wherever I look their project are in .ashx or .aspx file, while mine is in cshtml. This is a work project so I cant change the file format. You might see how I have already asked this question in the past with my attempts but it doesn't work. I have seen few videos online which they use controllers but for some reason my project doesn't have controller for that part (_search). If anyone could give me hints or tip how to make easiest autocomplete which connects to database it would mean the world to me. Thanks in advance :D <3

Comment: You just need a controller to get the data for the autocomplete. In web forms you can have ApiControllers, but you could also just use a `WebMethod` to get your data. Check out this [example](https://dotnetable.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/another-jquery-autocomplete-example-with-asp-net-webforms/), it uses a Web Froms `.asmx` WebService with a WebMethod to get the data.

Comment: @zgood i tried using web forms but it always messes up my project with lots of errors, the thing is I just got on board with the project and this is my task which I got stuck with, so I'm trying to find best solution to get autocomplete in .cshtml and .cs as its controller (using MS database server)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try this Assuming you are searching country in controller.

```
public JsonResult SearchCountry(string query){
    var dbResult=_context.Countries.Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().StartWith(query.ToLower())).Take(20).ToList();
return Json(dbResult);
}
```

In **CSHTML**

```
<input type='text' id='autocomplete' >
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
   // Fetch data
   $.ajax({
    url: "/demo/SearchCountry",
    type: 'get',
    data: {
     query: request.term
    },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( data );
    }
   });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
   // Set selection
   $('#autocomplete').val(ui.item.name); // In MVC5 change name to Name 
   return false;
  }
 });
```

Comment: What is _context.Countries.

Comment: Also my project is to search names of certain diagnosis

Comment: @denis He doesn't know how you are retrieving your data from the backend, `_context.Countries` is just a typical example. You didn't provide any code, so he cannot give you specific examples. Just replace that with how ever you get your data, or provide an example

Comment: the code `public static List<string> GetSearch(string searchdetails)
          {
              List<string> search = new List<string>();
              string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ebase.database"].ConnectionString;
              SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
              string sqlquery = string.Format("select Name from [dbo].[Diagnose] `

Comment: continued `where Name LIKE '%{0}%'", searchdetails);
              sqlconn.Open();
              SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
              SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
              while (sdr.Read())
              {
                  search.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
              }
              sqlconn.Close();
              return search;
          }` this is what I use to search for Name in database @zgood

Comment: This is what I used for script @zgood `$(function () {
        $("#search-diagnosis").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
          var param = {
           searchdetails: $('#search-diagnosis').val()
          };
          $.ajax({
           url: "AutoCompleteController/GetSearch",
           data: JSON.stringify(param),
type: "post",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
success: function (data) {
response($.map(data.d, function (item) { return { value: item } }))},});},minLength: 1});});`

Comment: @zgood or to put ti simple here is where my code is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836823/auto-complete-error-404-in-html-using-asp-net-and-jquery