# Need tip how to make easiest .CSHTML autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery, razor, http-status-code-404

I tried many methodes of making autocomplete in cshtml but no luck. In my project which I need to do names of diagnosis from (MS database), I got a task to do autocomplete but it always displays this error when I try my method of using jquery and ajax: error 404 for /Autocompletecontroller/GetSearch with this as an error also: When I open the jquery-1.8.0.js:8214 it shows me this xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null ); So I think I'm kinda starting to give up this point, so if anyone can help me somehow it would mean the world to me. FYI I cant do .aspx files with web forums because other people are in this project as well so I can't just simply change that.

Comment: you would need to provide some of your code here. did you check if the API works?

Comment: API works normal, there are elements in the tables database, here is where you can find my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836823/auto-complete-error-404-in-html-using-asp-net-and-jquery

Comment: It clearly states "not found". 
You are referring to the wrong URL. Is the APi really on your localhost?

Comment: @MaZoli yup its on the localhost well i think it is